# How to save and retrieve the canvas controls and its data in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, mvvm, prism

I am developing an WPF application to create forms dynamic, in which I have to provide a canvas to the end user. user drop controls from a toolbox containing textbox,labels, button, calendar etc which he can drag and drop to the canvas.Here user can set properties for each control.After the user has finished he would click the save button.

The canvas should now be saved into the database and the next time when user goes to retrieve it he should get the canvas in the same state where he left the last time so that he can continue editing. How to do this ? we are using PRISM framework? How to implement this without writing much code in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the canvas' *Children* property which returns a UIElementCollection of child elements of the Panel.